# cisco RV325 how to port forward to 3 web servers same LAN

Tags: cisco, port-forwarding

I have 3 devices on a LAN with local DHCP addresses and they both have web servers on port 8080. 
I want to access them from outside the LAN. 
I want to have 3 ports on the WAN side of the router forward to port 8080 on 3 different devices (& IP addresses) on the LAN.

```
Router WAN side        LAN IP        port
port:
8080       -->         192.168.1.100 8080
8081       -->         192.168.1.101 8080
8082       -->         192.168.1.102 8080
```

I was not able to add these to Port Address Translation, maybe 
because there is a pre-populated entry for Internal Port 8080 already. 
I believe this is technically possible--the router has enough information to 
forward the packets to the right device. Is it an arbitrary limitation 
of this model?

The Port Address Translation Service page was like this initially:

```
Service Management Table        Items 1-20 of 20 per page

Service Name    Protocol    External Port   Internal Port
   pre-populated:
...
FTP             TCP         21              21
HTTP            TCP         80              80
HTTP secondary  TCP         8080            8080
...
```

I tried to add the service: 
    httpDev1        TCP         8081            8080 
but it had no effect. It lets me save, no error message, but the new service is not in the list. I could not add even one entry using 8080 as Internal Port, let alone 3.

Comment: It might be a limitation of your router's interface, but you don't say what router it is so it's impossible for us to say.

Comment: look at title line

Answer (score 0):

Working now. 
We changed the external port from 8081 to 8095 and it worked. (forward 8095 to 8080).
So there is some problem with using port 8081.

As far as not able to save new service problem- someone else tried and it worked immediately. I don't know what I was doing wrong.